# Fredholm integral equation of the first kind

Tags: integral-equations

Can we solve the following specific integral equation:
$$
\int_0^1v^n(1-v)^{x-1}K(v)dv=f(x) ,x\in[0,1)
$$
If it is solvable, I wonder whether its solution can be represented in a closed form.

Comment: Solve for what?